# I Want to extract a certain number from string in java but not able to do so

Tags: java

I have a string like `String a = "I have 102 string but 123453 is best"`

So, In the above string i want to extract only 123453

This string keep getting changes but i always want to get that second number from this string.
What is the best possible way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If the string always have 2 numbers and you always want to extract the second one, then you could do it with regular expressions.

Comment: How do *you* know that this is the string you wanted? Is it because it is on certain position, or because this is second number, or because it is after some specific word, or maybe there is some other *logic*?

Comment: @MirekPluta what type of regular expression will be used in this? I have tried using regex- //d but it is giving me all the numbers in this particular string.

Comment: @Pshemo String will always have two numbers and I just want that second number in this string.

Comment: You can write regex *pattern* which represents *some* number, and let *matcher* to *find* it twice.

Comment: @Pshemo I still didn't got it. How to find it twice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example. First define your pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
```

Then define the string you want to test

```
String test = "I have 102 string but 123453 is best";
```

Create a matcher for that string

```
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(test);
```

Find once

```
matcher.find(); // find once
```

Find again, and if found, get the string

```
if (matcher.find()) { // find twice
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

For a complete, minimal and repeatable example, consider defining a method and defining the pattern as a constant:

```
static final Pattern P = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");

static String findSecondNumber(String test) {
    Matcher matcher = P.matcher(test);
    matcher.find(); // find once
    if (matcher.find()) { // find twice
        return matcher.group();
    }
    return null; // or alternatively return an empty string or a default value
}
```

Where `matcher.group()` returns the full match found; see also the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()).

Comment: `return test.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());` can be simplified with `return matcher.group();` since regex stores in group 0 full current match (and `group()` is same as `group(0)`).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a single `find()` with capturing groups. Here is how:

```java
    String a = "I have 102 string but 123453 is best"
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\d+.*(\d*).*$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(a); 
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1)); // this will print 123453
    }
```